# Is the Bellman-Ford algorithm a contraction mapping?

Tags: algorithms, fixed-point-theorems

I'm not sure this is the right community to ask this question, so feel free to move or close the discussion and point me to the right community.

I was wondering whether the Bellman-Ford (BF) algorithm can be seen as a contractive function, and hence admits a unique fixed point by the [Banach's fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

The BF algorithm is typically used to find shortest paths from a single source $s$ to any other node $u$ in a graph $G=(V, E)$, where V and E are vertices and edges. First of all, the BF update rule can be written as:

$T(d)_u = d_u = \min\{d_u, \min\{ d_v + w_{vu} : \forall v \in N(u) \}\}$

where $T: \mathbb{R}^{|V|} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{|V|}$ is the BF update rule, $N(u)$ represents the neighbourhood of node $u$, $w_{vu}$ is the edge weight from node $v$ to node $u$, and $d$ is initialized with $0$ for the source node (i.e., $d_s = 0$) and $\infty$ otherwise. Hence, if we consider the domain to be the space of vector distances, BF does have a fixed-point that corresponds to the optimal solution $d^*$ to which it converges in at most $|V| - 1$ steps (and from that point onwards, $T(d^*) = d^*$).

However, I'm unsure of how to formally prove that BF is a contractive function (if possible at all). I tried to prove on my own (unsuccessfully) that:

$||T(d) - T(d')||_p \leq ||d - d'||$

holds, where $d$ and $d'$ are the vector of distances of two successive iterations of Bellman-Ford. However, contractive functions usually require $d$ and $d'$ to be *any* input, so I am unsure that would even help.

Does anyone have any intuitions on how to prove that BF satisfies the contractive mapping theorem, or if this is possibile at all? Any references would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for Bellman–Ford to not terminate at all, if there is a negative cycle.

Even when restricted to nonnegative edge weights, it is possible to set initial distances such that they form different fixed points, as the algorithm blindly takes the minimum of (sum of incoming edge weight and neighbour distance) and (this vertex's distsnce) – a trivial example is where all edges are of weight $1$ and all distances are $0$.

Since we can make multiple fixed points for some networks, Bellman–Ford cannot be a contractive mapping.

Comment: Let me check if I understand correctly. You're saying that if you violate BF pre-conditions (setting all initial distances to 0), we're going to end up with a fixed-point which is obviously not the optimal solution, but yet is a different fixed point. Mmmh, that makes sense I guess. But what if we restrict ourselves to the correct initialization? Would we still end up having multiple fixed points?

Comment: @danin Under the assumption that there is no negative cycle, since the shortest distances are unique there is indeed exactly one fixed point. Even then, how do you handle infinities in the contraction map criterion?

Comment: That's one of the things that I couldn't figure out. If you suppose to use "big numbers" in place of infinities you lose generality. The way I thought about it is that given that there is a unique fixed point, it would likely be a contractive function. But I guess this is not always the case...